# Adding TextEditingControllers in a loop in Flutter isn't working

Tags: dart, flutter

What I try to achieve is for the TextInputField to be autovalidated once there is more than 1 character entered.

Here's my initState (simplified):

```
@override
  void initState() {
    autoValidateList.addAll([
      _autoValidateEmail,
      _autoValidateCompanyName,
      _autoValidatePhoneNo,
      _autoValidateName,
      _autoValidateSurname
    ]);

    textEditingControllersList.addAll([
      _emailController,
      _companyNameController,
      _phoneNoController,
      _nameController,
      _surnameController
    ]);

    for (int i = 0; i < textEditingControllersList.length; i++) {
      TextEditingController controller = textEditingControllersList[i];
        controller.addListener(() => () {
              print(
                  'Listener entered. companyName? ${controller == _companyNameController}');
              if (controller.text.length > 0) {
                print('=> true');
                setState(() => autoValidateList[i] = true);
              } else {
                print('=> false');
                setState(() => autoValidateList[i] = false);
              }
            });
    }
    _emailController.text = widget.loginData.email;
    super.initState();
  }
```

If I add the listeners not in a loop, for example:

```
_emailController.addListener(() => setState(() {
          if (_emailController.text.length > 0) {
            _autoValidateEmail = true;
          } else {
            _autoValidateEmail = false;
          }
        }));
```

It works fine.

None of the print statements get executed. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a very insidious error here. Notice that in your `addListener`, you're passing a function that returns a function. What you want to execute is the function that is being returned, but you're actually executing the function that you're passing.

In a more clear syntax, you're doing this:

```
controller.addListener(() {
  return () {
    // Your code
  };
});
```

So, what is happening is:

```
controller.addListener(() {
  print('This is going to be executed');
  return () {
    print('This is NOT going to be executed. Your code used to be here.');
  };
});
```

Instead of:

```
controller.addListener(() => () {
  ...           
});
```

You should be doing:

```
controller.addListener(() {
  ...           
});
```

Also, this is not related, but you should be calling `super` at the beginning of `initState`, not at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the initState note, I have seen it done both ways, and didn't know which one to use. Do you have an explanation what difference does it make?

Comment: I don't think it would make any difference in most situations, but it's a pattern Google stablished. Get inside your `super` call and you'll see Flutter's documentation about `initState`. Right at the end it's written: `If you override this, make sure your method starts with a call to super.initState().`